# call CodeIgniter Model with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to call a function in one of my model but I would like to do so without going through a controller, is that possible?
The code provided below doesn't work, I get `404 Not Found`

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/myApplication/usersModel/get_cash_player",
    success: function(result){
       alert("ok");
    }
});
```

My model (located in usersModel.php) :

```
public function get_cash_player(){                
   $currentUserID = $this->usersModel->get_user_id();
   $query = $this->db
       ->select('cash')
       ->from('users')
       ->where('id_player', $currentUserID)
       ->get();
   return $query->row('cash');      
}
```

Alternatively I could create a controller calling the method in the model but I would like to know if this shortcut is possible.

**Update 1:**
Okay, now comes the next question. For some of my controller I'm using a custom Helper because I want them available in several controllers. That works fine when calling them via PHP but can I create one for the `get_cash_player` controller mentioned above (and in the comments) and call it through Ajax?

I tried this but it is still not found:

```
if(!function_exists('get_cash_player')){
    function get_cash_player(){  
        $ci=& get_instance();
        $cash = $ci->usersModel->get_cash_player();
        return $cash;
    }
}
```

Comment: That kind of shortcut is not possible in CI MVC approach. It is because of url property of AJAX is trying to reach `example.com/controller_name/method_name/param`. For security reasons it is not possible to reach other application code through web browser.

Comment: "Alternatively I could create a controller calling the method in the model but I would like to know if this shortcut is possible." THAT is what you have to/should do. A model is not (or shouldn't be) accessible from the browser (AJAX or not), that is your data layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly calling the Model isnt possible, the Controller is the one always handling the process to and from View and the Model. This is the proper Codeiginter MVC approach,

[image: workflow]
source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/appflow.html

this link also may help you
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

But, you can do like this: use your ajax function to call a controller function to pass data through. The controller will handle the process with the model, and return data back to the ajax function.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is not possible. All incoming server requests are routed to controllers.