# Using $_POST values in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, post

Application makes an AJAX request to a method in a controller.

The controller then calls a method in the model to run a query on the DB and then return the results.

AJAX "type" specified as POST.

Even though $_POST superglobal values are available for use in model, should one still list the $_POST values in the model method signature?

I'm thinking this is best practice so people dissecting a system can quickly see inputs going into model methods

```
$this->Students_table_model->attendance_history_get($_POST['students_id'],$_POST['start_date'],$_POST['end_date']);

public function attendance_history_get($students_id,$start,$end)
```

VS

```
$this->Students_table_model->attendance_history_get();
```

and then just using the available $_POST values in model method attendance_history_get()

Comment: Refrer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514133/call-codeigniter-model-with-ajax

Comment: The post provided discusses how you can't bypass the controller to get direct access to the model in AJAX request.

I know enough at least to not try such things.

MY question was concerning simply if the $_POST values should be included in the Model method signature or can I just work with the POST values directly in the model method.

Either way works I am just wondering what people think is best practice.

Comment: dont do that in your model, pass it as argument instead.

Comment: @ponytails_soda can you specify real question in short please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use the codeigniter custom function $this->input->post(); to get the post value

```
$student_id = $this->input->post('students_id');
$start_date = $this->input->post('start_date');
$end_date = $this->input->post('end_date');
```

Comment: will put in controller like this and pass to model methods

the whole point was trying to reduce lines of code but it makes sense to run the CI post() methods on the incoming data

Comment: The Input Class serves two purposes:
It pre-processes global input data for security.
It provides some helper methods for fetching input data and pre-processing it.

Yeah gonna def. have to use that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$this->Students_table_model->attendance_history_get($_POST);
```

and use it in the model.